# splint: ask not to check system headers

Tags: c, static-analysis, splint

Is there a way to stop `splint` from analyzing system headers included, POSIX, libc etc.? I run with `-warnposix -preproc`:

```
% splint -warnposix -preproc my.c

/usr/include/unistd.h:220:8: Parse Error: Non-function declaration:
    __BEGIN_DECLS : int. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help
    parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

**UPDATE:**

```
% splint +posixlib +unixlib -I/path/to/myheaders -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu my.c

/usr/include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h:19:24: Parse Error:
    Suspect missing struct or union keyword: __signed__ :
    int. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
```

After reading [splint FAQ14](http://www.splint.org/faq.html#quest14) I tried to eliminate nonstandard keyword:

```
% splint +posixlib +unixlib -D__signed__= -I/path/to/myheaders -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu my.c

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/syslog.h:200:66: Parse Error:
    Inconsistent function parameter syntax: __gnuc_va_list :
    <any>. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

Declaring `__gnuc_va_list` as nonstandard keyword doesn't help in this particular case. I feel that `splint` is a powerful tool, but it requires to annotate almost every code it parses. Am I wrong?

Comment: Documentation: http://www.splint.org/faq.html#quest15

Comment: @jxh, thanks for comment. Please see my update. I wonder is there a way to ask `splint` do not check system headers at all?

Comment: You were also supposed to read: http://www.splint.org/faq.html#quest14 as the previous FAQ suggested.

Comment: @jxh, I did, however declaring nonstandard keywords won't help `splint` bypass. I updated the original post.

Comment: Try `signed` rather than empty. Also, `+gnuextensions`.

Comment: `splint` tries to be like the compiler, so it needs the prototypes to help do the static analysis. If it bypasses the system headers, you will just have a bunch of unknown function usage errors.